# Populating A Many-To-Many Table

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have two tables, The Instructor table, and the Department Table. The Instructor can be involved in many departments and the departments can contain many Instructors. I'm trying to populate the DepartmentInstructor table to create a many-to-many relationship. The tables are populated like so,

Department Table

```
DepartmentID    DepartmentName
    1           Aaron Copland School of Music
    2           American Studies
    3           Art
    4           Classical, Middle Eastern, and Asian Languages and Cultures 
    5           Comparative Literature
    6           Drama, Theatre & Dance
    7           English
    8           European Languages and Literatures
```

Instructor Table

```
InstructorID      InstructorFullName
1                 Abrams, Brian
2                 Ciavarella, Peter
3                 Franklin, Arnold
4                 Shur, Mitchell
5                 Reich, Toby
6                 Meyers, Allison
7                 Dana, Kathryn
8                 Rhindress, Mindy
```

What I'm trying to do is,

DepartmentInstructor Table

```
DepartmentID  InstructorID
1             3
3             7
2             7
6             4
```

Edit:

Responding to @GeorgeJoseph, We were also given a table that contains all of the data besides the IDs. This table is shown below,

Table X

```
Semester   Sec  Code    Course(HR,CRD)  Description     Day             Time                Instructor          Location   Enrolled    Limit      ModeOfInstruction
Spring 2019 02  37366   ACCT 100 (3, 3) Fin & Mgr Acct  T, TH           3:10 PM - 4:25 PM   Milo, Michael       KY 419         20        22         In-Person
Spring 2019 03  37823   ACCT 100 (3, 3) Fin & Mgr Acct  M               3:10 PM - 6:00 PM   Ho, Vivian          HH 17          21        22         In-Person
Spring 2019 01  37365   ACCT 100 (3, 3) Fin & Mgr Acct  T, TH           10:45 AM - 12:00 PM Milo, Michael       KY 419         22        22         In-Person
Spring 2019 06  7351    ACCT 101 (4, 3) Int Theo & Prac Acct 1  T, TH   12:10 PM - 2:00 PM  Feisullin, Anita    RA 201         30        30         In-Person
Spring 2019 12  7357    ACCT 101 (4, 3) Int Theo & Prac Acct 1  SU      8:20 AM - 12:00 PM  Mintz, Chana        PH 204         39        55         In-Person
Spring 2019 11  7356    ACCT 101 (4, 3) Int Theo & Prac Acct 1  S       8:20 AM - 12:00 PM  Chan, Joseph        PH 110         54        55         In-Person
Spring 2019 10  7355    ACCT 101 (4, 3) Int Theo & Prac Acct 1  F       6:30 PM - 10:30 PM  Solarsh, Eva        PH 212         30        30         Hybrid
Spring 2019 09  7354    ACCT 101 (4, 3) Int Theo & Prac Acct 1  T, TH   8:50 PM - 10:30 PM  Zapf, Michael       PH 110         29        55         In-Person
```

I added the data to the Instructor Table and the Department table through this table. Let's call this table X. The DepartmentName was created by using a case statement over the Course(HR,CRD) column.

Now to answer your question, Table X should help us in forming that many-to-many relationship between the Instructor and the Department Table. I'm currently not sure how to map the relationship. What I tried doing was this,

```
  SELECT DISTINCT [Description], Instructor
    FROM Schema.X AS x
    INNER JOIN [College].[Instructor] AS I
    ON x.Instructor = I.InstructorFullName
```

This will then give me the corresponding course taught by a professor but I'm unsure of how to go from here.

Edit 2:

Here's how my DB design looks,

[image]

Comment: You are on the right path. Is there a logic to be used to populate the DepartmentInstructor table that you are facing trouble with?

Comment: There should be something that binds a Course to a department Name in the Department Table. Once you get this your join using the Instructor name should get you the output you are looking for

Comment: I think you are almost there. If you use [Course(HR,CRD)] to create the departmentname, then add that field to you department table. Then you simply join you instructor and department table to the X table, and you get the values. It seems that [Course(HR,CRD)] is the business key for department, and [Instructor] is the business key for instructor in table X

Comment: I do see your point. What confuses me though is that I'm going to have to build a separate table called Course. That table will contain the Courses from table X. Which leaves me thinking, what exactly the department name should be.

Answer (score 0):

As George and yourself have mentioned, you are almost there.
 I am using SQL Server / T-SQL

In my example you have a course table, an instructor table and a department table.
The course table must have the instructorID and the departmentID as a column. 
This is how you bridge the gap between all the tables. It means that you have a distinct list of departments, courses (with the linking department and tutor IDs) and a distinct list of tutors. There are considerations where a course has more than one tutor (Could happen I suppose) but test out what suits your setup. Probably add a new row to courses with the same departmentId and the 2nd tutorID.

I have added some extra columns in the output.
You can also see not all departments have courses assigned to them. Lack of funding!  
Also note I have used left join where inner might work better depending on your situation or where clause. EG Where courseID is not null.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/cf48b/1/0

Comment: Thank you for the input. Yes, I ended up adding the distinct departments, courses, and tutors to prevent data anomalies.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so, through some trial and error and thoroughly reading through the data. I've come to a solution that I believe to be correct,

```
INSERT INTO [College].[DepartmentInstructor]
    (DepartmentInstructorID, DepartmentKey, InstructorKey)
SELECT
    NEXT VALUE FOR [Project3].[SequenceObjectForDepartmentInstructorId],
    DepartmentID,
    InstructorID
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT InstructorID, DepartmentID
    FROM Uploadfile.CoursesSpring2019 AS CS
        INNER JOIN [College].[Instructor] AS I
        ON CS.Instructor = I.InstructorFullName
        INNER JOIN [College].[Department] AS D
        ON CS.[Course (hr, crd)] LIKE CONCAT('%', D.DepartmentName, '%')
) AS Result
```

I've been able to progress further in my project and I'm about 95% done. I've actually stumbled onto a somewhat similar problem. If you refer back to the database design that I posted, the courses table will need the IDs from multiple tables. This is what I've come up with,

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        TS.TimeSlotID,
        I.InstructorID,
        BL.BuildingLocationID,
        C.CourseID
FROM Uploadfile.CoursesSpring2019 AS CS
   INNER JOIN [College].[TimeSlot] AS TS
       ON CS.[Time] = TS.[ClassHours]
   INNER JOIN [College].[Instructor] AS I
       ON CS.[Instructor] = I.[InstructorFullName]
   INNER JOIN [College].[BuildingLocation] AS BL
       ON CS.[Location] LIKE CONCAT( BL.[BuildingName], '%')
   INNER JOIN [College].[Course] AS C
       ON CS.[Course (hr, crd)] LIKE CONCAT(C.CourseName, '%')
```

The problem here is that this query results in approximately 1mil rows. Table X has approximately 4700 rows which means that this query that I currently have is nowhere near the number of rows I should have since.